# App Icon back arrow shows in landscape and portrait

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have an app that is using an ActionBar (actually ActionBarSherlock) which contains two fragments, one a listing and one a details fragment.  When the device is in portrait mode and the user clicks from the listing view to the details view I'm setting `setHomeButtonEnabled` on the details view, so the user can click the App Icon to go back to the listing (and the back arrow is displayed automatically).

When the device is in landscape mode, and both fragments are displayed on the screen, I still see the back arrow next to the App Icon, which doesn't make any sense, as there's nothing to go back to.

Not sure if I need to do something, in code, so the back arrow doesn't display in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to get the results I wanted by adding this code to the details fragments.  Probably not ideal, but it works:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        this.getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

Update:

Found this is probably a better solution.  It detects if the "details" fragment is visible or not:

```
final DetailsFragment fragment = (DetailsFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentDetails);

if (fragment == null || fragment.isInLayout() == false)
    this.getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```